# Selenium IE Upload File not Working

Tags: selenium, internet-explorer

Adding this in case anyone else has this issue.

I was having issues uploading file with Selenium through IE.
(The file path would get set, but the file would not upload.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was this line: `InternetExplorerOptions.introduceFlakinessByIgnoringSecurityDomains();`.

I had to remove that line and instead set Internet Explorer's (IE) Security "Enable Protected Mode" settings to the same value.